# How to create a this Matrix by Numpy , and sort the matrix at second row?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I want to create a matrix by Numpy as follow:

the first column composed by 0 and 1 , in this case , the value is not important
the second column composed by integer , I want to sort my matrix by this column.

```
[[[1,1,1,1,1] , [3]],
 [[0,0,0,0,0] , [2]],
 [[1,1,1,1,1] , [5]]]
```

The question is:
 - How to create matrix like that?
 - After created , how to sort this matrix by second column

and get the answer as follow:

```
[ [[0,0,0,0,0] , [2]],
  [[1,1,1,1,1] , [3]],
  [[1,1,1,1,1] , [5]] ]
```

I'm fresh in numpy, I tried a lot but didn't succeeded, please help.

Comment: Don't understand your matrix notation... What do the mean by the `[2]`, `[3]` and `[5]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, I used newlines to format this code for clarity by putting your matrix rows onto separate lines. This is NOT necessary, but I feel it helps show the content of each row (basically a list with five items and a list with one item).

When defining a numpy array, you can also define the datatype (dtype) with both a field name and the type of data stored in that field. Lists are considered an `object` type by numpy, so for each row, I assigned a field name to each item in the row ('x' and 'y') and I assigned a data type of `object`.

```
n = np.array([ ([1,1,1,1,1] , [3]), 
               ([0,0,0,0,0] , [2]), 
               ([0,0,0,0,0] , [5])], 
               dtype=[('x', object),('y', object)]
```

Numpy arrays all have a builtin method called `.sort()` that enables you to sort the rows. If you give it an order argument using the name of a field, it will sort by the field (i.e. that column). In this case, we sort by the 'y' field/column.

```
n.sort(order='y')
```

Comment: this answer works well

Now I'm trying to init a matrix like this format , so that I can dynamically put new values in, do you have any advice?
thanks

Comment: i think i found the anwser : 
np.zeros((2,),dtype=[('x',np.int32,(5)),('y',np.int32)])